# Need help setting up cloudwatch alarm for elb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am trying to create two cloudwatch alarm on my Elastic LoadBalancer. Suppose there is 3 instance attached to my elb.

***If one instance goes unhealthy then I should trigger an alarm saying it's a WARNING and if all instance is unhealthy then I should trigger an alarm saying it's a CRITICAL.***

I am experimenting with cloud watch metrics MAX, MIN, AVG and I am not getting right condition to put into.

This is what I am doing right now.

> For CRITICAL if maximum no of healthy host < 1 .

This works but is taking a long time for creating that alarm.

> For WARNING if maximum no of unhealthy host > 0.

I dont have much confidence in this because I am not able to verify this .

Comment: how much time its taking for creating these alarms ?

Comment: @AmitK I don't have exact time but I guess it more than 10 minutes. Do you have idea what might causing this to happen ?

Comment: aws don't push these metrics before 5 mins, if you want you can enable fine  grained metrics which update in 1 min but there is extra charge for it. also read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html#ViewingDataUsingCloudWatch

Comment: It was waiting for instance be to unhealthy before alarm got triggered which was 10 calls each in every 5 sec interval. That what was taking that time. I validated and everything works fine now !